# How does Multi Login Extension works?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I just want to know how does Multi Login Extension works. I already read all the documentation in chrome but I didn't see any Session duplication like multilogin does.

This is the link of this extension.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multilogin/nccllfnllopfpcbjdgjdlfmomnfgnnbk?hl=en

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "session duplication"?

Comment: @Xan - If you use Multilogin extension, you can login in some website like facebook using different usernames without using incognito.

Comment: I'm not sure how ethical this is but I copied the source files over and re-published MultiLogin since it seems to have disappeared.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/openmultilogin/plaahcaagklllbcjognjgcnldgjnjhpb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With MultiLogin installed, there is still a single `CookieStore` like before. But MultiLogin has its own persistent storage for the cookies that belong to each profile. When a cookie is set, MultiLogin records it and remembers the associated profile. When a link is clicked, MultiLogin intercepts the request and creates an HTTP header for only the cookies in that profile. And when some JavaScript evaluates `document.cookie`, MultiLogin provides a getter that knows the cookies for that profile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Chad Parry. So, most likely, they can get our Login Credentials right?

I tried to open their code but its encrypted.

Comment: The extension has access to your passwords and session tokens, whether they are in your cookies or any other part of the request. Most likely the extension doesn't publish your passwords anywhere. However, it does call home with some information, and I wasn't able to decrypt the extension enough to figure out exactly what. Probably they just want to collect usage metrics. I chose to not use this extension just to be safe, however.